# AngularJS 2 calling a directive inside another one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to follow the angualrJS 2.0 tutorial on calling another component inside another one. However I'm getting an error saying that it is not a known element on the `<main-footer></main-footer>` selector. What am i doing wrong?

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  // use templateurl for template files
  template: `
    <h1>My First Angular App 22</h1>
    <main-footer></main-footer>
  `,
   directives: [FooterComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { 

}

// footer.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-footer',
  template: `
    <h2>The footer</h2>
  `,
})
export class FooterComponent{ 

}
```

**EDIT**

So I got it working, by declaring and importing the file in `app.module.ts` as well as the `app.component.ts` file Thanks to the help from @Chang I did not see this in the tutorials on AngualrJS 2.0

```
// app.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { FooterComponent }   from './footer.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, FooterComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can try to declare "FooterComponent" in your app.modules ?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: See my revised code for the final solution that made it work